# is there any way to conditional Debugging in android studio

Tags: android, debugging, conditional-statements

Is there any way to have conditional Debug in android studio?
for example I wanna go to debug mode when a specific variable value is.
for example:

```
for(MyClass myclass: ClassList){
String title = myclass.gettitle(); // this is where break point is
}
```

Before that I do not need the debug mode. I just wanna examine the app on that exact value. for example when `title="KickBoxing`" in this case I should check the variable value and if it is not my required value I should press **F9** to go to next value. maybe this takes 50 times to get to my desired value.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is possible to add a condition for a breakpoint. Add a breakpoint, as you normally do, and click with the right mouse button on it. You will be prompt with a dialog. In the *condition* you can put some java code.

E.g. you could put `"kickBoxing".equals(title)`

this way the debugger will stop on that breakpoint only when the condition is true.

[image]

(photo taken from http://javafortesters.com/)

Comment: sorry you right. it was my mistake. thanks for helpful answer

Comment: It helps for my debug.

Comment: It helps for my debug.

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with `Android Studio`:

1. Set a breakpoint on the line you need.
2. Right-click on the breakpoint
3. Paste your condition into the field named **Condition**

For example, your condition should be like `myclass.gettitle().equals("KickBoxing")`

Comment: your answer is right too but 
Blackbelt post the answer before you. but I appreciate and up-vote your answer too

Comment: @Kenji, you are right. Unfortunately, Blackbelt post came up already while I was writing my answer, so he should take the honour by the right.